# Looping images from folder in to photo gallery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I want to loop images from image folder in to photo gallery. I'm using ruby on rails without database. I'm still learning build with ruby on rails, so my code so far looks like this and I get error.

**static page html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="galleria">
   <% @images.each do |image| %>
   <%= image_tag image.gsub("app/assets/images/", "")  %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

**static page**

```
def image
  @images = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/galleria/*.jpg")
end
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Where is your `image` method?

Comment: Solved, added code in top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***SOLVED***

This code worked for me

```
<% Dir.glob('app/assets/images/galleria/*').map do |path| %>
<%= image_tag "galleria/#{ File.basename(path) }" %>
<% end.reduce(&:+) %>
```

Comment: Yeah i change places. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
<% Dir.glob('app/assets/images/galleria/*').map do |path| %>
  <%= image_tag "galleria/#{ File.basename(path) }" %>
<% end.reduce(&:+) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be much logic or ruby code in views : it should be moved to helpers, controllers or models.

Your `html.erb` could look like this :

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="galleria">
   <% @images.each do |image| %>
     <%= image_tag image  %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

You need to initialize `@images` in the corresponding controller. This step was probably not done, so `@images` was nil and you got `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` error.

In your controller :

```
@images = Dir.chdir(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images')) do
  Dir.glob("galleria/*.jpg")
end
```

This needs to be written in the correct action. If your `html.erb` is `app/views/articles/index.html.erb`, then `@images` should be defined inside the `index` method in `ArticlesController`.

Comment: Still i get 'undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass'. 
I did like you wrote. Second lines I added in def index

Comment: Passing variables between controllers and views is a very important Rails feature. This should work, and it should work reliably. Where exactly is your view, where exactly is your controller and index method?

Comment: My view is in static_pages folder (gallery.html.erb) and my index method is in static_pages_controller.rb (class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController)

Comment: Okay i got it. I added action in wrong method. Thanks for help!